# insert query is not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I really don't know what is happening insert query is not working for me.

```
$query_getgreenyear = "INSERT INTO `greenityear` `ConsolidateYear` VALUES ('".$sentdata."')";
```

in $sentdata the value is ('A','B') and the datatype for `ConsolidateYear` is varchar.I need this value to be inserted into the database.
but i am getting error 
You have a SQL syntax error near '`ConsolidateYear` VALUES ('('A','B')')'  at line 1.
Please help me in this regard.
I am new to database activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to place a `bracket()` for your column name.

Try this:

```
$query_getgreenyear = "INSERT INTO `greenityear` (`ConsolidateYear`)
 VALUES ('".$sentdata."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html).

You need to surround your column name with parantheses in your INSERT statement:

```
$query_getgreenyear = "INSERT INTO `greenityear` (`ConsolidateYear`) VALUES ('".$sentdata."')";
```

And I would highly recommend you to use prepared statements as provided by your MySQL-extension (at least if you're not using the deprectated mysql_connect). This protects you against SQL injections.

Comment: @Thanks All.. Got my mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `greenityear` (`ConsolidateYear`) VALUES (...)
```

But, you really should be using prepared statements and not constructing statements as you are.

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is

```
INSERT INTO `tablename` (`columnname1`,`columnname2`) VALUES ('value1','value2')
```

so your example would be like this:

```
$query_getgreenyear = "INSERT INTO `greenityear` (`ConsolidateYear`) VALUES ('".$sentdata."')";
```